# How to see the individual memory usage of php scripts?

Tags: ubuntu, php

I just experienced a lot of memory usage in my server. So, found out that php-fpm is the one who is eating my memory. Now, how can I know whats the exact location of the problem? How to see which php script is taking too much memory? (Im running an Ubuntu server)

Comment: Try running one at a time and watch what resources are used by each.

Comment: Can't do that... im using wordpress :)

Comment: Maybe you should reword your question and include all relevant information.

Comment: Id't be happy to... what are the information you need?

Comment: Is php-fpm 'eating your memory' because it has spawned too many processes or because of the files it is running? Wordpress' backend (admin pages) tend to take a lot of memory - and extensions are often the culprit. Try to profile the site with XDebug, you may get some useful information. Likewise, you may consider setting a memory limit with Suhosin (suhosin.memory_limit), it will log the filepath and line number of any script that tries to exceed the limit. Also, consider setting up PHP-FPM's slow log - it is not directly related, but may point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks my friend! I just found the problem :) Now its back to normal :D